# Get Windows Login details in Java Web Application

Tags: java, windows, authentication

What is the procedure to get Windows Login Details in java?
Ours is a web application, need to get Windows login username.
any thoughts folks

-PD

Comment: what do you mean by Login Details? just user name? domain,etc..?

Comment: Hello Jhurtado Thanks for your response. The windows machine login id and domain in web application.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript

```
var userName='';
var userDomain='';

var wshshell=new ActiveXObject("wscript.network");
//write to some (hidden) form field
with (document.formname) {
    userName=wshshell.username;
    userDomain=wshshell.userdomain;
}
wshshell=null;
```

you can pass the variables to hidden parameters and submit them along with form or pass them using ajax. !

Comment: Wouldn't that fail in anything other than IE?

Comment: my apologies ! its better to use some third party SWF(Flash object) or Java Applet which detects username and domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is about as good as you are going to get. It requires the user be using IE.
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0441.html

Comment: Seems to work in Chrome. It works in Firefox but will prompt for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

From a web app?

Comment: I'd have to check, but I believe that would retrieve the user that the web app is running as, not the remote user's credentials.