# Start-up Login Screen using Java that prevents user from skipping authentication and gaining access

Tags: java, authentication, login-control

I am trying to make a Log-in screen that load immediately after the user Logs in the Operating System (Windows Log-in, etc) and before he could initiate any process.

I want the screen to be locked, basically avoiding the user to manipulate with the authentication process and preventing the user to implement controls like crl+alt+del (or esc) else alt+tab.

It is actually a client server authentication where my server has the user database and it is must that the user cannot skip the Log-in.

Since its about tracking all the events of the user I wish to get the username and the password at the start-up to start the Log maintenance. If the user can some how skip the authentication, them my system fails.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your question is fairly broad and you may find it difficult getting it answered as is.  Can you make the question more specific and perhaps demonstrate some things you've already tried?  This will help your question get attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done — you essentially cannot circumvent Ctrl+Alt+Del. A far better option is to leverage the user's original Login.

Comment: Sir can I have a bit more explanation about the alternative you suggested. A reference or something. Thank You

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628561/get-windows-login-details-in-java-web-application

Comment: Sir basically the user can be any one, as in case of a College Lab environment. Windows cant be given the task of handling huge number of account (Account for each student). That is the main reason I am trying to use another authentication after windows log-in where in the user account details would be retrieved from the server. I guess I did clear a bit of my idea, as if what I wish to code

Comment: I know its been too long to get back, but finally I jumped off to C# and got the task done. Seriously, it made things easy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my question was wrong, but things can be done with JAVA or C++/C#.

I progmatically changed the registry values of corresponding Group Policy editor to launch the task manager. I disabled the shutdown, restart, task manager and other such options (from windows) that were posing a threat to my application (where in the user could kill the process) and would reset the values back once the user authentication was complete...

If this isn't the right way, suggestions and comment would be appreciated.